# Regex expression to match update_1_0_3_to_1_0_4 in java

Tags: java, regex

What is the correct regular expression  to match the following string in java ?

update_1_0_3_to_1_0_4

I tried

```
boolean t1= files.matches("^update_\\d_\\d_\\d{1,2}$\\_to_\\d_\\d_\\d{1,2}$");
System.out.println("The strings match " + t1);
```

However, it doesn't work and thus, returns false.

Comment: Why do you have a `$` in the middle, which indicates the end of the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"^update_\\d_\\d_\\d{1,2}_to_\\d_\\d_\\d{1,2}$"`

All I did was remove `$\\` from the middle. `$` means end of string (so it should only be at the end, of course) and `_` does not need to be escaped so the `\\` before it was unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

`$` means "end of string", so `...$\\_...` will never be what you want (it means "end of string, followed by underscore").

In fact, `String.matches` already matches against the entire string, so `^` and `$` are mostly redundant. And you don't need to escape `_`. Putting it together:

```
boolean t1= files.matches("update_\\d_\\d_\\d{1,2}_to_\\d_\\d_\\d{1,2}");
System.out.println("The strings match " + t1);
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter RegExp:`^update(_\\d){2}_\\d{1,2}_to(_\\d){2}_\\d{1,2}$`

Or even this: `^update(_\\d+){3}_to(_\\d+){3}$`

As others have said, the `$` in the middle can be removed.